# Toilet tank won’t fill

Tags: plumbing

My toilet tank only fills when another toilet in the house is flushed.after a different toilet is flushed the other toilet fills with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a sticky fill valve.  When the 2nd toilet is flushed, the slight change in water pressure may "un-stick" the fill valve.

When the toilet tank is not filled, lift the tank lid and move the fill valve arm up and down and see if it starts working.

It's not hard to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Have to agree with Steve...probably a stuck valve. To make it more reliable you might want to replace the "guts" in the tank.   Toilet tank "guts" are inexpensive (under $20 generally) and easy to replace, even by a novice DIY'er  .